# Rotating a sprite on a Bezier curve in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, bezier

I am trying to make a sprite follow a bezier curve. I found a few forum posts over on the cocos2d site and followed the directions but i still dont seem to be able to get the sprite to rotate correctly. Can anyone help.

The code i have added into the update method of the BezierBy function is as follows

```
float qx = (powf(1-t,2)*xa + 2*(1-t)*t*xb+powf(t,2)*xc);
float qy = (powf(1-t,2)*ya + 2*(1-t)*t*yb+powf(t,2)*yc);

double deltaX = x-qx;
double deltaY = y-qy;

double degrees = (-180/M_PI)*ccpToAngle(CGPointMake(deltaX,deltaY));

[target_ setRotation:degrees];
```

The original article can be found [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1376)

Any help would be great at the moment the rotation seems quite erratic

Comment: I have uploaded a picture of the issue, in the photo you can see the dog is not rotated to the direction of the line [link](http://twitpic.com/950mgp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever I need a sprite to follow on a particular Bezier path and rotate accordingly. I create a bezier path using `CCBezier`.
And use CCRotateTo method for rotating the sprite to a particular angle. The duration of rotation is duration of bezierAction and angle of rotation can be calculated manually. Like in your pic angle is from -45 to 45.
So code might look like this..

```
ccBezierConfig bezier;
bezier.controlPoint_1 = ccp(0, s.height/2);
bezier.controlPoint_2 = ccp(300, -s.height/2);
bezier.endPosition = ccp(300,100);

id bezierForward = [CCBezierBy actionWithDuration:10 bezier:bezier];
[sprite runAction:bezierForward];

[sprite setRotation:-45];
[sprite runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:10 angle:45]];
```

Fill values accordingly.. This is just a snippet code.. :)

Comment: Thanks but i am not sure this will work with multiple control points and a start position

Comment: this might work.. but for multiple control points you might need to add rotate actions in CCSequence.. M nt sure as I neva tried this.. :)

Comment: Thanks, i have solved the problem by just having an array of multiple points and rotating while moving.

Comment: Any chance there's a more elegant solution to this now? I'm trying to do this but setting multiple points to do the rotation isn't cool to me :( Maths is neededd yet I suck at it! Ideas?!?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you calculate the angle of the sprites movement during the last frame and use this value to rotate the sprite accordingly. This method will work for every type of movement including complicated bezier paths. This will also save you the work of timing the rotation to the movement compared to the other solution offered.

```
CGPoint vector = ccpSub(sprite.position, lastPosition);
sprite.rotation = atan2(vector.x, vector.y) * 180 / M_PI;
lastPosition = sprite.position;
```

You will of course need to put this code in an update loop with `lastPosition` as a global variable.

Comment: You will of course need to put this code in an update loop with lastPosition as a global variable.